# Sharp spikes in unknown signal

Tags: signal-analysis, demodulation, bpsk

I am trying to decode an unknown signal, which has those really weird spikes/jumps.
My assumption is that it is somehow **(B)PSK** modulated but the signal looks really odd as shown in the screenshot. The screenshot shows the **Phase plot** of the recording drawn by Inspectrum.
[image: Phase plot drawn by Inspectrum] I recorded the signal close to the source multiple times using a **B210** with varying samples rates and gains as well as varying setups but I always get the same result. I also tried something called **phase unwrapping** which looked really promising in the beginning but didn't get me far.

Does anyone know how I may proceed or give me any kind of hint to what it is?
I would appreciate any help!

*Edited 1*:
One more Screenshot with a **Phase Plot in the upper drawing** and an **Amplitude Plot in lower drawing**.

[image]

*Edited 2*:
I tried both of the standard **phase unwrapping functions** in **Python and MATLAB** but this did not remove any of the weird spikes/jumps.

Comment: Just a hint, part of the signal looks like it is suffering from data type overflow errors. Notice for example that between the spikes, there is a "smooth" waveform part which however appears "upside-down". Therefore, I would suggest that you either change the final data type you save data from the USRP or the data type Inspectrum uses when parsing the signal.

Comment: Are you sure? I recorded with GNU Radios USRP Source block and the output type is the default complex float32 and I don't think you can change the data type Inspectrum uses. I added one more screenshot together with an amplitude plot.

Comment: @A_A I forgot to mark you

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I've closed this question because I believe it is a problem with **phase unwrapping**.  Please look at the linked duplicate, and see if that's the problem. If it isn't, or if you need more information, please edit your question, ping me and I'll reopen for answers.

Comment: @PeterK. I tried both of the standard unwrapping functions in python and matlab but this did not remove any of the weird spikes. Could you please reopen it again?

Comment: Please add the code you used and add the output.